# Print the same columns as a new line cutting after delimiter in awk

Tags: awk, delimiter

I have a file having contents like :

```
1 18997 19003 ABCP@CC;8CYUS|ABCP@CC;8C|ABCP@CC;8C|XXYG;UY|UOO98,|ABCP@CC;8CYUS
2 87737 93837 AASC
```

So, some lines have a 4th column with delimiter, and some not.

What I want to have is, to cut whenever I see a `"|"`, and append the first 3 columns as new line:

```
1 18997 19003 ABCP@CC;8CYUS
1 18997 19003 ABCP@CC;8C
1 18997 19003 ABCP@CC;8C
1 18997 19003 XXYG;UY
1 18997 19003 UOO98,
1 18997 19003 ABCP@CC;8CYUS
2 87737 93837 AASC
```

Then I will apply `uniq` and remove the duplicates.
I have tried to do :

`awk '{split($0,a,"|"); print a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]}'`
 However it only splits the 4th column in the same line and doesnt append it to new line.

How can I get the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to print once for every item in the array you extracted.  And of course, only split the fourth field.

```
awk '{ n = split($4, a, "|"); for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) print $1, $2, $3, a[i] }' file
```

If you want to make sure output is unique, Awk can do that too.

```
awk '{ n = split($4, a, "|");
    for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) {
        x = $1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS a[i]
        if (!seen[x]++) print x } }' file
```

Comment: But if I dont have any delimiters, it prints "1"

Comment: Then the example data in your question is incomplete. What does a line look like which doesn't have the delimiters? Maybe add `/\|/` as a condition before the opening brace.

Comment: yes I have edited. sorry for the wrong example I gave earlier

Comment: Works for me; did you copy/paste it incorrectly? Maybe reload the page because I edited the answer a few minutes ago, though it's not visible here (edits within a 5-minute "grace period" are not displayed).

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
awk '{ s= $1 FS $2 FS $3; gsub(/\|/,RS s" ") }1' infile
```

OR

```
awk -F'[ |]' '{for(i=4; i<=NF; i++)print $1,$2,$3,$i}' infile
```

***Input:***

```
$ cat infile
1 18997 19003 ABCP@CC;8CYUS|ABCP@CC;8C|ABCP@CC;8C|XXYG;UY|UOO98,|ABCP@CC;8CYUS
2 87737 93837 AASC
```

***Output:***

```
$ awk '{ s= $1 FS $2 FS $3; gsub(/\|/,RS s" ") }1' infile
1 18997 19003 ABCP@CC;8CYUS
1 18997 19003 ABCP@CC;8C
1 18997 19003 ABCP@CC;8C
1 18997 19003 XXYG;UY
1 18997 19003 UOO98,
1 18997 19003 ABCP@CC;8CYUS
2 87737 93837 AASC

$ awk -F'[ |]' '{for(i=4; i<=NF; i++)print $1,$2,$3,$i}' infile
1 18997 19003 ABCP@CC;8CYUS
1 18997 19003 ABCP@CC;8C
1 18997 19003 ABCP@CC;8C
1 18997 19003 XXYG;UY
1 18997 19003 UOO98,
1 18997 19003 ABCP@CC;8CYUS
2 87737 93837 AASC
```

***Edit- for unique***

```
$ awk -F'[ |]' '{split("",arr);for(i=4; i<=NF; i++){if(!($i in arr))print $1,$2,$3,$i; arr[$i]}}' infile
1 18997 19003 ABCP@CC;8CYUS
1 18997 19003 ABCP@CC;8C
1 18997 19003 XXYG;UY
1 18997 19003 UOO98,
2 87737 93837 AASC
```

Comment: I have edited my input, sorry that I gave an incomplete one earlier

Comment: @bapors did you try ??

Comment: The `uniq` variant doesn't catch dupicates from different input lines. Depending on your input constraints, that could be a bug, or a feature (copes better with big input files because it forgets what was on previous lines, i.e. doesn't use up all your memory even if you process multiple gigabytes of data).

Comment: @tripleee Sorry, I couldn't reply on time, I perceived it as unique in each record, rather than, unique in all records

Comment: Yeah; perhaps we will never find out. (-: